# Существуют ли вирусы на языках программирования, которые не компилируются в машинных код?

Tags: java, c#, .net, безопасность, вирусы

Собственно, интересно, а существуют ли вирусы, которые написаны на какой-нибудь JAVA или .NET и вообще возможно ли существование?

В минусы подобных платформ можно отнести то, что:

1. Можно без особых проблем декомпилировать вирус и получить исходных код, что позволит в кротчайшие сроки получить лекарство
2. Необходимость Runtime программ. Правда, Microsoft начали по умолчанию поставлять новые Win с .Net

Comment: ИМХО сейчас можно написать вполне легальный с точки зрения антивируса скрипт, который, например, удаляет все пользовательские файлы и даже запрашивает подтверждение своих действий у пользователя, пихнуть его в инсталлятор или авторан и в 8 из 10 случаев пользователь кликнет ОК а потом будет бегать кругами по потолку и материть вездесущих хакеров, хотя его черным по русскому спрашивали, согласен ли он с тем что программа собирается сделать. Так что дыры в безопасности надо затыкать начиная с прокладки между стулом и клавиатурой =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

По сути, любая программа, выполняющая (вредоносные) действия, которых не ожидает пользователь, может быть воспринята как вирус. Т.о. совершенно не важно на чем написана такая программа, главное, чтобы ей были предоставлены соответствующие привилегии (удаление файлов, взаимодействие по сети и т.д.). Т.о. если она не работает в сугубо изолированном окружении, т.н. "песочнице", она вполне может реализовать свои вредоносные намерения.

Comment: В строгом понимании термин "вирус" подразумевает заражение и самораспространение. А вот такого на .NET, например, я не видел. Хотя, думаю, такое может быть.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вопрос в том, есть ли что-то что помешает этим действиям именно из-за того, что приложение выполняется в управляемой среде (по сравнению с нативным приложением)? Мне кажется, что нет.

Comment: Мне тоже кажется что нет. С другой стороны, формат .NET файлов и, соответственно, внедрение в них кода существенно сложнее обычных MZPE. Наверное потому и нет полноценного вирья на .NET

Answer (score 5):

Конечно!

Раньше были очень распространены вирусы на Visual Basic. Например, классический [вирус ILOVEYOU](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ILOVEYOU).

Из более старого — [макровирусы](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81) под Microsoft Office.

Comment: ILOVEYOU написан на vbscript, а не на Visual Basic

Answer (score 5):

Трояны на .NET вполне себе бывают, сейчас это даже не редкость. Мальварь под Андроид по большей части как раз на жабе писана. Макро-вирусы сейчас широко используются, там VBA. Трояны на JS - массовое явление.

Answer (score 4):

Существует целый класс -- "скрипт-вирусы", которые точно никуда не компилируются, ЕМНИП скорость написания лекарства не помогает, если вирус расползается быстрее чем лечится. LoveLetter - за сутки более 2 млн. компьютеров. + многие "бут-вирусы" некоторые были написаны на javascript c запуском с autorun.html.